# Call a list of varying types using a string as the variable name

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there was a way in C# to pass a function a string for a parameter and it use that string to call a list that has the name the string said and use it in the function

For instance:

```
List<int> BurgerPrices = new List<int>{1, 2, 4};

public int SetupPage(string pageName, string listName) {
    return listName[2]; 
    // something like this where I can put the string in and then use it to call a list
}

BurgerPrice = SetupPage("Sub Categories", "BurgerPrices");
```

In other words, call a List by its variable name using a string and then be able to index/modify it

Comment: you can use reflection for that?

Comment: You should use a dictionary of lists instead of a bunch of fields.

Comment: You can use an expression to build a function for that. But I think that this is an overkill!